# CURL on PHP 5.2 works in CLI but not in IIS

Tags: windows, iis, php, curl

I have a Windows 2003 Server running IIS with php 5.2.8,  I'm trying to use CURL, and it works in CLI mode (if i execute php.exe) but it does not seem to be registered when running under IIS.

The output of PHP info in both CLI and IIS show the same 'Loaded Configuration File', but under IIS it does not give the CURL info box.

c:\program files\php\php.exe -i shows

```
...
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini
...
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8i zlib/1.2.3
```

phpinfo()

```
...
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini
...
```

NOTE: This server also runs php 5.3 in c:\program files\php-5.3.0 and CURL does properly work with that installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Copy sselay32.dll and libeay32.dll on your windows path(C:\windows) and restart IIS Server .You should be able to see that